# How can I handle internet availability in my UWP app?

Tags: uwp, template10

My application uses internet services to fetch and save data. If I try to use these without connectivity I can receive an error. I also want to indicate to the user that there is no connectivity and it is required.

How can I do this effectively?

PS: I use the Template 10 framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To handle this pragmatically, you first need to ensure you have upgraded to using Template 10 1.1.12 or higher. With this version you can use the `NetworkAvailableService` to test not only internet connectivity but also general network available, too - depending on if your application is an internal app accessing local resources or an external app accessing internet resources.

```
public override async Task OnNavigatedToAsync(object parameter, NavigationMode mode, IDictionary<string, object> state)
{
    var net = new NetworkAvailableService();
    net.AvailabilityChanged = async e =>
    {
        if (await net.IsNetworkAvailable())
        {
            // yes network 

            if (await net.IsInternetAvailable())
            {
                // yes internet
            }
            else
            {
                // no internet
            }
        }
        else
        {
            // no network
        }
    };
}
```

Handling the UI portion of the question is another issue. You can have an IsConnected INPC property in your view-model that causes the visibility of a UI element to change. Or you could use the wonderful `NetworkConnectionStateTrigger` to change your visual state. That's how I would do it, by the way. It's the textbook approach, for certain.

Get the State Triggers from https://github.com/dotMorten/WindowsStateTriggers

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup>
        <VisualState x:Name="connected">
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <triggers:NetworkConnectionStateTrigger ConnectionState = "Connected" />
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="MyTextBlock.Text" Value="Internet is available" />
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="disconnected">
            <VisualState.StateTriggers>
                <triggers:NetworkConnectionStateTrigger ConnectionState = "Disconnected" />
            </VisualState.StateTriggers>
            <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Target="MyTextBlock.Text" Value="No internet connection"/>
            </VisualState.Setters>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

Best of luck!